# Linking GCC(G++) ASM object with .cpp objects not working(undefined reference to...)

Tags: windows, gcc, compilation, g++, mingw

I have two functions that I need to write directly on ASM, as GCC will include pre/post call codes when compiling those functions, and I don't want that.

Assume that as a immutable: I have to compile two functions directly on asm.

Two functions are implemented as:

```
    .intel_syntax 
    .text
    .globl  Func1
    .def    Func1;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef    
Func1:  
    push 1
    push esp     
    mov eax, 0xDEADBEEF
    call eax 
    ret   

    .globl  Func2
    .def    Func2;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
Func2:
    ret
```

I'm generating objects using: g++ -c asm.S -o asm.o . And that works! I have a asm.o with no error/warnning.

But, when compiling all codes as:

```
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o release\Test.exe ../Test/asm.o release/main.o release/mainwindow.o release/funcs.o release/qrc_a.o release/moc_mainwindow.o  -lpsapi -lOleAut32 -lmingw32
```

I got the follow error:

```
release/funcs.o:funcs.cpp:(.text+0x5c4): undefined reference to `Func2()'
release/funcs.o:funcs.cpp:(.text+0x5d0): undefined reference to `Func1(HINSTANCE__*)'
release/funcs.o:funcs.cpp:(.text+0x6a5): undefined reference to `Func1(HINSTANCE__*)'
```

So the linker can't find Func1 and Func2 objects... but I included asm.o(at ../Test/asm.o) on compiling, so I don't know what's wrong :(.

Thanks for any help o/

Btw: I'm using g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 from MinGW, so I'm at Windows environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is looking for a function `Func1()` not just a symbol name, `Func1`, so it will be looking for a symbol matching the mangled name of that function. You haven't defined any such symbol, you have defined `Func1` instead, without a mangled name.

You need to declare the functions as `extern "C"` in the C++ file so that the linker just looks for `Func1` which is what you have defined in the asm.

Comment: That ahahaha... I always use C, and barely C++ that I just forgot about that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The C++ compiler is looking for name mangled functions (with calling parameter types).

`extern "C" int func1();` and maybe asm => `_func1`.